# Should I unit test messages that don't return a value?

Tags: unit-testing

In [*Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby: An Agile Primer*](http://www.poodr.info/book/), the author writes, "[An object] is responsible for testing its own interface and it does so by making assertions about the results that these [incoming] messages return. … These messages need tests because other application objects dpeend on their signatures and the results they return."

She explains that "the first requirement for testing an incoming message is to prove that it returns the correct value in every possible situation," giving this as an example unit test for the `diameter` method for a hypothetical `Wheel` class:

```
def test_calculates_diameter
  wheel = Wheel.new(26, 1.5)
  assert_in_delta(29, wheel.diameter, 0.01)
end
```

My question is, **what about incoming messages that don't return a value?** I have an object whose public interface only has two methods that don't return a value but merely change the state of the receiving object. Do I still need to test that object? and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typing the question, I think I've realized the answer: to use the author's nomenclature, I should **test the outgoing "command" messages that are sent in response to the incoming messages**.

For some context, the author later writes, "Many outgoing messages do have side effects (… an action is taken by an observer) upon which your application depends. These messages are *commands* and it is the respondibility of sending object to prove that they are properly sent."

In my case, my object is a container that sends messages to its children when its state changes, so that object's test should ensure that those messages are sent to its children.